# Installation of camlp4 with opam on OS X 10.9 failed

Tags: macos, ocaml, opam

I do not understand why this installation on a fresh opam installation failed.

Fresh means that there was no .opam directory
I run opam init
and then opam install ocamlfind, which worked

followed by opam install camlp4, which failed.

what's wrong?

```
$ opam install camlp4
The following actions will be performed:
 - install   camlp4.4.02.1+system
=== + 1 ===

=-=- Synchronizing package archives -=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=   

=-=- Installing packages =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=   
Copying ~/.opam/repo/default/packages/camlp4/camlp4.4.02.1+system/files/install to ~/.opam/system/build/camlp4.4.02.1+system/
Copying ~/.opam/repo/default/packages/camlp4/camlp4.4.02.1+system/files/check-camlp4.sh to ~/.opam/system/build/camlp4.4.02.1+system/
Building camlp4.4.02.1+system:
  sh ./check-camlp4.sh
[ERROR] The compilation of camlp4.4.02.1+system failed.
Removing camlp4.4.02.1+system.
  Nothing to do.


#=== ERROR while installing camlp4.4.02.1+system ==============================#
# opam-version 1.2.0
# os           darwin
# command      sh ./check-camlp4.sh
# path         $home/.opam/system/build/camlp4.4.02.1+system
# compiler     system (4.02.1)
# exit-code    1
# env-file     $home/.opam/system/build/camlp4.4.02.1+system/camlp4-94259-58c514.env
# stdout-file   $home/.opam/system/build/camlp4.4.02.1+system/camlp4-94259-58c514.out
# stderr-file  $home/.opam/system/build/camlp4.4.02.1+system/camlp4-94259-58c514.err
### stdout ###
# ...[truncated]
# 4.02 by switching to a local installation via `opam switch 4.02.1`.
# 
# Here are some installation instructions for camlp4 if you obtained OCaml
# via the OPAM binary packages:
# 
# http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3Aocaml&package=ocaml
# 
# * Debian/Ubuntu: sudo apt-get install camlp4-extra
# * RHEL/CentOS/Fedora: sudo yum install ocaml-camlp4
# 
### stderr ###
# ./check-camlp4.sh: line 3: camlp4orf: command not found
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually the answer is already contained in the OPAM output. Just to clarify, you're using system compiler, i.e., a compiler that is already installed on your operating system (using macports or brew). That means, that camlp4 being de facto a part of compiler, is needed to be installed from the system too. So, you need either install it using your package manager, e.g.,

```
 sudo port install ocaml-camlp4
```

or just switch to a local installation (the recommended way). This will require you to create a new compiler installation,

```
 opam switch 4.02.1
 eval `opam config env`
```

And afterwards everything will work as a charm.

Comment: It's also worth reporting upstream to MacPorts that `opam` should depend on the `ocaml-camlp4` and `aspcud` packages.  The Homebrew package already does this.

Comment: `aspcud` unfortunately is not packaged in macports. What concerning `ocaml-camlp4`, well strictly speaking it doesn't depend.

Comment: There is a ticket open for MacPorts aspcud here: https://trac.macports.org/ticket/46843

Comment: Also, I would consider `ocaml-camlp4` to be a hard dependency of OPAM for now, since none of the available package repositories will compile without it.  There is an ongoing migration away from this hard dependency, but it'll take some time.